# Возможно ли получить идентификатор объекта в другом приложении, на который установлен фокус/на который был клик?

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли каким-нибудь образом получить идентификатор объекта стороннего приложения, на элемент которого установлен последний фокус/на элемент которого был клик? Это может быть текстовое поле, какая-нибудь кнопка и так далее.

В моём случае для теста хотелось бы получить идентификатор поля в блокноте(как стороннее приложение, изображение 1).

Для настоящей практики необходимо получить идентификаторы выделенных зон(ввод и чистка) 2-го изображения(стороннее приложение yandex браузера - консоль).

При получении самого объекта, возможно ли получить доступ к изменению чего-либо в нём? К примеру, как это есть у своих стандартных c# windows forms приложений:

```
textBox.Text = "Text";
```

Этот вопрос служит дополнением к данному: [Как выполнить JS в открытом браузере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030663/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-js-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5), но может быть издан, как отдельный.

[image: Тестовое изображение, в котором фиолетовой линией подчеркнуто то поле, идентификатор которого нужно получить]

[image: Изображение, в котором фиолетовыми линиями подчеркнуты элементы, идентификаторы которых нужно получить]

Comment: Знаете, я прочитал ваш вопрос, а так же прошлый, и скажу одно, если будет стоять браузер `firefox`, то вы ничего не сможете скопировать в консоль [`JS`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZp0K.png). И да, если вы будете эмулировать нажатие клавиш, то у вас тоже ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @ヒミコ Приоритетнее всего стоят yandex и chrome, в которых изначально и планировалось моё приложение. Тем, кому я буду давать программу можно запросто сказать, чтобы использовали поддерживаемые браузеры. Также, можно сказать пользователю, чтобы ввёл "разрешить вставку" сам, а после кликнул на кнопку программы. Лучше, подскажите, собственно, ответ на вопрос.

Comment: [spy++](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) - возможно это, что вам нужно (почитайте описание)

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц Просмотрел, использовал Finder Tool. Однако [он захватывает всё окно консоли](http://joxi.ru/xAeB5avURovX7r). Как получить с него отдельные объекты?

Comment: @NickTheTrick если приложение использует полностью кастомную отрисовку элементов управления, а не строит свое окно из "окон" - то никак. Если Spy++ или его аналог показывает, что кроме всего окна ничего нет - значит, с точки зрения системы, там действительно нет стандартных элементов, а то, что вы видите - нарисовано вручную на одном большом окне.

Comment: @PashaPash Нашёл способ по координатам. Прекрасно подходит для клика по кнопке чистки. Однако для текстового поля он не работает. _SendMessage(consoleRender, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)0x30, MakeParam(32, 65));_ не подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

public static Control GetFocusedControl()
{
    Control focusedControl = null;

    IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus();
    if(focusedHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Работает только с .NET контролами. Иначе возвратит null.
        focusedControl = Control.FromHandle(focusedHandle);
    }
    return focusedControl;
}
```

источник: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetFocus.html

Comment: То-то, что работает только с .NET контролами. В консоле браузера таковых нету. Необходим правильный код отправки сообщения приложению по координатам с текстом. Только как будет правильно? Сейчас у меня такое использование: _SendMessage(consoleRender, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)0x30, MakeParam(32, 65));_ , однако оно игнорирует координаты.

Comment: @NickTheTrick в самом вопросе было о блокноте, а не о браузере. С блокнотом сработает.

Comment: Хорошо, для теста в блокноте подходит, спасибо, но дальше написано следующее: _Для настоящей практики необходимо получить идентификаторы выделенных зон(ввод и чистка) 2-го изображения(стороннее приложение yandex браузера - консоль)._

Comment: @NickTheTrick как минимум половину вопроса решает. :) Вобщем-то я и в самом ответе сразу написал что работает только с .NET контролами.